# Visual Studio Code Bazel extension logs

Tags: visual-studio-code, bazel

I'm trying to figure out what's going on in the background when I use the Bazel extension in VSCode. In particular, I'm interested in the exact `bazel` commands VSCode issues and the result of the command executions. Where can I find such logs? I'm guessing that `bazel` might be throwing some errors, but I can't tell ... because I can't look at the command output.

Comment: related: https://github.com/bazelbuild/vscode-bazel/issues/64